# Why am I not getting a similar output for ResourceFunction["CubicMonotonicInterpolation"]?

Tags: interpolation, resourcefunction

```
`DamOne1u05jun2023 = {{-3., 51.79}, {-2., 51.79}, {-1., 51.79}{0., 51.79}, {0.558859, 51.818}, {1.15496, 51.758}, {1.66534, 51.561}, {2.11133, 
  51.423}, {2.68188, 51.177}, {3.24688, 50.997}, {3.7365, 
  50.619}, {4.10219, 50.484}, {4.74384, 50.43}, {5.1841, 
  50.6}, {5.88854, 49.907}, {6.34383, 49.867}, {6.95258, 
  49.905}, {7.44298, 49.99}, {7.89274, 50.072}, {8.35978, 
  50.101}, {9.03468, 50.164}, {9.57814, 50.22}, {10.1469, 
  50.253}, {10.6237, 50.283}, {11.3136, 50.353}, {12.1321, 
  50.461}, {12.6542, 50.512}, {13.2418, 50.58}, {13.7236, 
  50.621}, {13.7933, 50.636}, {14.3619, 50.619}, {14.8468, 
  50.639}, {15.4053, 50.672}, {15.8458, 50.672}, {16.4413, 
  50.682}, {18.075, 50.663}, {18.5709, 50.636}, {19.1007, 
  50.652}, {19.6825, 50.793}, {20.2412, 51.081}, {20.7553, 
  51.275}, {21.1724, 51.492}, {21.8153, 51.846}, {22.3113, 
  52.726}, {22.8038, 53.216}, {23.836, 54.176}, {23.8433, 
  53.984}, {23.8433, 53.984}, {24., 53.984}, {25., 53.984}, {26., 
  53.984}}

SpDamOne1u05jun2023 = 
 ResourceFunction["CubicMonotonicInterpolation"][DamOne1u05jun2023]
`
```

[image: Two different outputs for the function I am attempting to use. I would like to get the InterpolatingFunction output.]

I'm attempting to interpolate a cubic function that would illustrate one cross section of a small creek. The data I'm inputing is the {delta x, elevation} for each point recorded in the field. All of my other attempts at using this ResourceFunction have worked, expected SpDamOne1u05jun2023.

Comment: There may be known bugs in Resource Functions.

Comment: Plese provide Mathematica code! This will increase your chance getting helpful hints!

Comment: You have a duplicated point, at least at the precision of the data presented. (`{23.8433, 53.984}`)

Comment: Thank you, the duplication was messing with the interpolation! I appreciate it.